# Multithreaded Client Server chat application using MFC CSocket and CWinThread

Tags: multithreading, mfc, asyncsocket

I'm trying to develop a chat application using MFC. In my program there will be Single Server and multiple Clients. I Need help in clearing some roadblocks.

Since there are multiple clients involved I need to use threading concepts. I have created a one to one chat application but can't realize the same using Threads(CWinThread).

[The UI of the application that I need to create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUWje.jpg)

I have set parent for 2 CSocket on my OnInitDialog()

```
    BOOL CChatSampleDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();


    // TODO: Add extra initialization here
    m_nSocketType = 0;
    m_strServerName = _T("loopback");
    m_nPort = 4000;
    UpdateData(FALSE);

    m_ListenSocket.SetParent(this);
    m_ConnectSocket.SetParent(this);

    return TRUE; }
```

When a Client connects to a sever my OnAccept() function executes. It is in this function I want my Socket handle to be detached and attached the handle to the thread. And the Thread does the rest. I need help in realizing this thread that manages the communication. What I have done is I created a derived class from CWinThread. on each OnAccept() a new object of this thread class is created and the SOCKET handle is attached to it.(I have created a handle as a member function inside my derived thread class)

This is Derieved Thread Class

```
class CSockThread :
    public CWinThread
{
public:
    CSockThread();
    ~CSockThread();
    SOCKET m_hConnected;
    CSimpleSocket m_sConnected;

public:
    virtual BOOL InitInstance();
};
```

This is the code that I have done but I am not clear how to use threading here. I need help in using CSocket and Threading to complete my chat application.